# How to Horizontall Scrolling with mouse move?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created asp.net web page with horizontal scrolling . I need to scroll it on mouse move . That panel consists with rad grid. I have try with  [this](http://jsbin.com/uninug/3/edit)

But its not working,

This is my panel

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlAssetDetailGrid" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal" >
 </asp:Panel>
```

Please can any one help me to this with best solution

Comment: Did you tried this example with wich browser? This works well here using Chrome!

Comment: I need to provide solution with compatible all the browsers

Comment: I have tried with IE 8 and  FireFox